# I can not connect to MySQL server that I just installed

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have installed MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04 :

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.7 mysql-server-5.7
```

to check the installation I run this command :

```
mysql --version

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

And as well :

```
 systemctl status mysql.service

● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-10-06 16:34:36 CEST; 28min ago
  Process: 3521 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3511 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3520 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─3520 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Oct 06 16:34:35 SV1080AP1105 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Oct 06 16:34:36 SV1080AP1105 systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

But when I'm trying to connect it does not work !!!

```
sudo mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: You have to use a password, I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

For fresh installs, MySQL 5.7 & above saves the temporary password in the log. That might help.

Then using the password, do this:

```
    sudo mysql -u root -p RETRIEVED_PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you have install the client package ?

Please refer to  : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of MySQL (5.7 >) and at least MariaDB (10.something >) have the `root` user authentication set to `auth_socket`.

This means that the `root` login can only be used with the root user.

try:

```
sudo mysql
```

This can be changed, and often does, as it gets in the way of a lot of development environment stuff, so there's plenty of topics on how to do it, should you need to.

Comment: it really is going to depend on how your user account on ubuntu is set up.
I'd expect if `sudo mysql` doesn't work, then simply `mysql` itself (if your account is already a root/super user).  If that still fails, you might have to reset the root password for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mysql.html
```

You Can try this....i hope it will work fine